# SQL Cannot add foreign key restraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code for SQL and continually get errors in trying to create the foreign key. I have no idea what I am doing.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDatabaseOne`.`Teams` (
    `idTeams` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '    ',
    `Semester` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `Year` YEAR NOT NULL,
    `Captain` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `Sport` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idTeams`),
    INDEX `fk_Teams_Students_idx` (`Captain` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_Teams_Sports1_idx` (`Sport` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Teams_Students`
      FOREIGN KEY (`Captain`)
      REFERENCES `myDatabaseOne`.`Students` (`idStudents`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Teams_Sports1`
      FOREIGN KEY (`Sport`)
      REFERENCES `myDatabaseOne`.`Sports` (`idSports`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: What errors do you constantly get? Please post the exact error message(s).

Comment: Do they have the same data type?

Comment: Do you need the apostrophe's?

Comment: This should get you there [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33212987#33212987)

Comment: Do the keys in the other tables have indexes on them? Do these foreign keys already exist?